# GetFolderItems not returning FolderItems and EnvelopeID

Tags: soapui, docusignapi

Edit - can someone please post results of a **soapUI test** where a request to GetFolderItems shows returned values for tag FolderItems?  I really don't understand why or how this is coming back empty.  If I change the FolderPath or FolderID to be empty, I get:

```
<soap:Body>
      <soap:Fault>
         <faultcode xmlns:q0="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">q0:Security</faultcode>
         <faultstring>Security requirements are not satisfied because the security header is not present in the incoming message.</faultstring>
         <faultactor>https://demo.docusign.net:7801/api/3.0/api.asmx</faultactor>
      </soap:Fault>
```

Original question:

I'm using soapUI 5.3.0 to make a GetFolderItems request from a folder named "Standard Test Folder" in my sandbox account.  in the response is empty.  I have a signed document I can see in this folder, so why is the envelope ID not coming back in soapUI?

raw request sensitive data masked:

```
POST https://demo.docusign.net/api/3.0/api.asmx HTTP/1.1
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Content-Type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8
SOAPAction: "http://www.docusign.net/API/3.0/GetFolderItems"
Content-Length: 2367
Host: demo.docusign.net
Connection: Keep-Alive
User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.1.1 (java 1.5)

<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:ns="http://www.docusign.net/API/3.0" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soapenv:Header><wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd"><wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="UsernameToken-username-token-here"><wsse:Username>[my-integrator-key-here]my-username-here</wsse:Username><wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">my-password-here</wsse:Password><wsse:Nonce EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary">aNWMeSvYyYaRVcgymLdaCQ==</wsse:Nonce><wsu:Created>2017-08-15T18:35:55.981Z</wsu:Created></wsse:UsernameToken></wsse:Security></soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <ns:GetFolderItems>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <ns:FolderFilter>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <ns:AccountId>my-account-id-here</ns:AccountId>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <ns:FolderOwner>
               <!--Optional:-->
               <ns:UserName>my-username-here</ns:UserName>
               <!--Optional:-->
               <ns:Email>my-email-ID-here</ns:Email>
            </ns:FolderOwner>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <ns:FolderTypeInfo>
               <!--Optional:-->
               <ns:FolderType>Normal</ns:FolderType>
               <!--Optional:-->
               <ns:FolderName>Standard Test Folder</ns:FolderName>
               <!--Optional:-->
               <ns:FolderPath/>
               <!--Optional:-->
               <ns:FolderId>d9ac99ca-64d4-4a06-8344-4db12f89a502</ns:FolderId> 
            </ns:FolderTypeInfo>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <ns:StartPosition>0</ns:StartPosition>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <ns:FromDate>2017-08-08T06:00:00</ns:FromDate>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <ns:ToDate>2017-08-16T06:00:00</ns:ToDate>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <ns:SearchText>?</ns:SearchText>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <ns:Status>Any</ns:Status>
         </ns:FolderFilter>
      </ns:GetFolderItems>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

raw response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: private, max-age=0
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
X-RateLimit-Reset: 1502823600
X-RateLimit-Limit: 1000
X-RateLimit-Remaining: 987
Date: Tue, 15 Aug 2017 18:35:56 GMT
Content-Length: 677
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains
Content-Encoding: gzip
Connection: Keep-Alive

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
<soap:Header>
<wsa:Action>http://www.docusign.net/API/3.0/GetFolderItemsResponse</wsa:Action>
<wsa:MessageID>urn:uuid:e7ad7be0-de1d-4286-9d6b-ef18353e39d3</wsa:MessageID>
<wsa:RelatesTo>urn:uuid:994f2eb3-9c00-49f5-a28d-ff91a139190a</wsa:RelatesTo>
<wsa:To>http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing/role/anonymous</wsa:To>
<wsse:Security>
<wsu:Timestamp wsu:Id="Timestamp-ce8081d4-80a8-45c1-8344-ac94d83eefa2">
<wsu:Created>2017-08-15T18:35:56Z</wsu:Created>
<wsu:Expires>2017-08-15T18:40:56Z</wsu:Expires>
</wsu:Timestamp>
</wsse:Security>
</soap:Header>
<soap:Body>
<GetFolderItemsResponse xmlns="http://www.docusign.net/API/3.0">
<GetFolderItemsResult>
<ResultSetSize>0</ResultSetSize>
<StartPosition>0</StartPosition>
<EndPosition>0</EndPosition>
<FolderTypeInfo>
<FolderType>Normal</FolderType>
<FolderName>Standard Test Folder</FolderName>
</FolderTypeInfo>
<FolderItems />
</GetFolderItemsResult>
</GetFolderItemsResponse>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove

```
<!--Optional:-->
<ns:SearchText>?</ns:SearchText>
```

from your request, it will show you the envelopeIds in the response

Comment: Awesome!  This fixed it. I'm now getting a response with <FolderItem> and                <EnvelopeId>
I guess the lesson learned here is, watch out for those >?< in the example requests! - Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Make a first API call to GetFolderList to get the list of folders and then make sure you use the same folder name as it appears in the GetFolderList response.

Comment: I am using the exact same values for I got below for the call to GetFolderItems:
<FolderType>Normal</FolderType>
<FolderName>Standard Test Folder</FolderName>
and
<FolderId>d9ac99ca-64d4-4a06-8344-4db12f89a502</FolderId>

Comment: Those values above came from a first call to GetFolderList, then I used the same values for the call to GetFolderItems